# "i want certain columns in entity class to not to create columns in table,is there any solution or annotation for that"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PassengersDetails")
public class PassengerDO {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="inc",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="inc")
    @Column(name="PassengerId")
    private int PassengerId;

    @Column(name="PassengerName")
    private String PassengerName;

    @Column(name="PassengerAddress")
    private String PassengerAddress;

    @Column(name="PassengerPhoneNo")
    private String PassengerPhoneNo;

    @Column(name="PassengerPassword")
    private String PassengerPassword;

    @Column(name="PassengerConfirmPassword")
    private String PassengerConfirmPassword;
```

> " certain columns in entity class should not to create columns in the
>   table, is there any solution or annotation for that"

in my entity class i dont want to store all the columns in a table,i want ignore specific columns, can you help me to approch this problem

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  What about this partial entity class do you not like right now?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **@Transient** annotation which tells the JPA provider to not persist the field in the database.

> Specifies that the property or field is **not persistent**. It is used to
>   annotate a property or field of an entity class, mapped superclass, or
>   embeddable class.

```
    @Entity
    public class Employee {
        @Id int id;
        @Transient User currentUser;
        ...
    }
```

[You may Refer the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use that column for calculation purpose and don't want to Store in database then `@Transient` annotation works for you.

Like if you don't want to Store column `PassengerAddress` then declare in this way.

```
@Transient
private String PassengerAddress;
```

Or other option is use partial class i.e remove that column from class. only use particular columns which yo want to store in database.

Answer (score 1):

For ignoring any field from your model you can use `@Transient (javax.persistence.Transient)` annotation so it will not check that column in your db.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your column not to be inserted or updated, you can make the column `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`.

Quoting from JBoss Hibernate [Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping):

> insertable (optional): whether or not the column will be part of the
>    insert statement (default true)
>
> updatable (optional): whether or not
>    the column will be part of the update statement (default true)

If you want `PassengerPhoneNo` not to be inserted or updated in the database table you can have `insertable = false` and `updatable=false` as shown below:

```
@Column(name="PassengerPhoneNo", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private String PassengerPhoneNo;
```